# jQuery rotate/transform

Tags: jquery, transform, rotation

I'd like to use this function to rotate then stop at a particular point or degree. Right now the element just rotates without stopping. Here's the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       var $elie = $("#bkgimg");
       rotate(0);
       function rotate(degree) {

           // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
           $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
           // For Mozilla browser: e.g. Firefox
           $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});

           // Animate rotation with a recursive call
           setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },65);
       }
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply remove the line that rotates it one degree at a time and calls the script forever.

```
// Animate rotation with a recursive call
setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },65);
```

Then pass the desired value into the function... in this example `45` for 45 degrees.

```
$(function() {

    var $elie = $("#bkgimg");
    rotate(45);

        function rotate(degree) {
      // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
           $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
      // For Mozilla browser: e.g. Firefox
           $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        }

});
```

Change `.css()` to `.animate()` in order to [animate the rotation with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  We also need to add a duration for the animation, 5000 for 5 seconds.  And updating your original function to remove some redundancy and support more browsers...

```
$(function() {

    var $elie = $("#bkgimg");
    rotate(45);

        function rotate(degree) {
            $elie.animate({
                        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        'zoom': 1
            }, 5000);
        }
});
```

**EDIT:**  The standard jQuery CSS animation code above is not working because apparently, jQuery `.animate()` does not yet support the CSS3 `transforms`.

This jQuery plugin is supposed to animate the rotation:

[http://plugins.jquery.com/project/QTransform](https://github.com/puppybits/QTransform)

Comment: That just rotates the image. I really want it to animate/rotate and stop at a certain point or degree. Sorry, I should have mentioned that before. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrea, I'm looking at your page in Safari and the image is rotated 45 degrees.  Looking at the DOM in the console, it's showing the proper CSS of `-webkit-transform` has been applied.  Maybe your browser does not support CSS 3.

Comment: @Andrea, sorry, I forgot to mention the "duration" required for animation.  I edited it again.

Comment: @Andrea, jQuery `animate()` does not support `transforms` I just learned.  Here is a plugin that is supposed to do it.  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/QTransform

Comment: I got it. I'll have to work on the doc a bit. Thanks for your help. I have tried some other plugins but couldn't get them to go. Maybe this is the one!

Answer (score 12):

It's because you have a recursive function inside of rotate.  It's calling itself again:

```
// Animate rotation with a recursive call
setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },65);
```

Take that out and it won't keep on running recursively.

I would also suggest just using this function instead:

```
function rotate($el, degrees) {
    $el.css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
      '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
       '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
          'transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
               'zoom' : 1

    });
}
```

It's much cleaner and will work for the most amount of browsers.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use, toggleClass on click?

js:

```
$(this).toggleClass("up");
```

css:

```
button.up {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
               /* IE6–IE9 */
               filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157,M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104, sizingMethod='auto expand');
                 zoom: 1;
    }
```

you can also add this to the css:

```
button{
        -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

which will add the animation.

PS...

to answer your original question:

you said that it rotates but never stops. When using set timeout you need to make sure you have a condition that will not call settimeout or else it will run forever. So for your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
     var $elie = $("#bkgimg");
     rotate(0);
     function rotate(degree) {

      // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
    $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
      // For Mozilla browser: e.g. Firefox
    $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});


    /* add a condition here for the extremity */ 
    if(degree < 180){
      // Animate rotation with a recursive call
      setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },65);
     }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with some kind of solution to the problem. It involves jquery and css. This works like toggle but instead of toggling the display of elements it just changes its properties upon alternate clicks. Upon clicking the div it rotates the element with tag 180 degrees and when you click it again the element with tag returns to its original position. If you want to change the animation duration just change transition-duration property.

**CSS**

```
#example1{
transition-duration:1s;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function ()  {  var toggle = 1;
  $('div').click( function () {
      toggle++;
      if ( (toggle%2)==0){
          $('#example1').css( {'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'});
      }
      else{
          $('#example1').css({'transform': 'rotate(0deg)'});
      }
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
t = setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },65);
```

and `clearTimeout` to stop

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

I use this with AJAX

```
success:function(){ clearTimeout(t); }
```