# jquery onmouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to rotate an image onmouseover function using Jquery

**file.js**

```
$("#logo").rotate({
        bind:
         {
             mouseover: function () 
             {$(this).rotate({ animateTo: 180 })},
             mouseout: function () 
             {$(this).rotate({ animateTo: 0 })}
        }
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/file.js"></script>
<img id="logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="none" />
```

Is there anything wrong in this code? BTW, I found this code on the internet.
There is no function call as rotate() in JavaScript then how can it work? Please give any link so that I can understand.

Please ignore this question if it looks like a foolish thing to ask :)

Comment: a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/Db3CW/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936396/jquery-rotate-transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download jquery.rotate.1-1.js from here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/downloads/list and include it in a script tag before this call.

Answer (score 1):

`.rotate()` isn't a function. Are you referencing whatever plugin this is correctly?
This must be what's causing the issue.

Comment: i need to call the function from image onmouseover()
what should i replace with rotate() then?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to use some code snippet that is using a custom JQuery plugin.

There is no built-in function for rotating images in JQuery. There are plenty of plugins available for that, e.g. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/ and http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/.